# Getting android specific attribute in custom component

Tags: java, android

I have my own custom component in xml written like this

```
    <com.app.components.CustomComponent
        android:id="@+id/component"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Attrs:

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomComponent">
    <attr name="android:scaleType"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

My custom component constructor looks like this

```
@Bind(R.id.imageView) ImageView imageView;
@Bind(R.id.progressBar) ProgressBar progressBar;

public CustomComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FunGuideImageView, 0, 0);

  // how to correctly get scale type defined in xml ?
    int scaleType = a.getValue(R.styleable.CustomComponent_android_scaleType,
            ImageView.ScaleType);


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageview, this, true);
    ButterKnife.bind(view);
    imageView.setScaleType( scaleType );

}
```

How can I get the scaleType defined in xml and set it to my imageView?

Comment: Shouldn't `CustomComponent` being extending `View`?

Comment: Indeed CustomComponent is extending View. How does this help ?

Comment: If you extended `ImageView`, you can simply do `getScaleType()`, otherwise, I don't think making your styleables the same names as the `android:` attributes is a good idea.

Comment: If I am extending ImageView I cannot inflate my custom xml anymore. So at the moment I am extending LinearLayout

Comment: Why not? As far as I can tell you are making a custom ImageView that includes a ProgessBar.

Comment: In such case inflater.inflate( says cannot resolve method if I extend ImageView instead of extend LinearLayout

Comment: I don't understand why that wouldn't resolve. LayoutInflater is not bound to anything other than the Context.

Comment: because you have to pass parent viewgroup to inflater so extending imageview does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the first two files, You have to make the following changes in order to get it work:

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomComponent, 0, 0);
int scaleTypeIndex = a.getValue(R.styleable.CustomComponent_android_scaleType, -1);
```

Then you can get the `ImageView.ScaleType` array doing the following:

```
if(scaleTypeIndex > -1) {
    ImageView.ScaleType[] types = ImageView.ScaleType.values();
    ImageView.ScaleType scaleType = types[scaleTypeIndex];
    imageView.setScaleType(scaleType);
}
```

Remember to trash the `TypedArray` after use.

Comment: I had to use val scaleType: Int = a.getInt(R.styleable. CustomComponent_android_scaleType, -1) ... a.getValue returns a Boolean ... but it works with a.getInt